# How can one inflate 2 fragment views from hosting activity at the same time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this code in my main activity for the fragments.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mainView2"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**And i use this code in my main activity to inflate the fragments**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainView,new MainViewFragment())
                .add(R.id.mainView2,new SecondProductLayout())
                .commit();
```

But i'm still getting the 1st fragments view, what am i doing wrong and how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Why is mainView2 inside mainView? Shouldn't mainView2 be below mainView?

Comment: @ChinLoong theoretically it should but then it will complain about multiple root tags.

Answer (score 0):

split the activity screen two parts inflate your fragment in your activity

Answer (score 0):

You can add static fragments in your xml . 
See those links :

- https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html
- http://android-kaizen.com/2014/09/20/adding-fragments-to-activities/
- http://android-kaizen.com/2015/01/04/tutorial-multi-pane-fragments/
- [Supporting different screen sizes with dynamic or static fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236052/supporting-different-screen-sizes-with-dynamic-or-static-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You got to split your layout into two parts using weight and inflate two fragments as usual we do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:context="com.android.buffer.exampleapplication.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/flFragment2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java code to inflate the fragment.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragment1, FragmentA.getInstance(msg)).commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragment2, FragmentA.getInstance(msg)).commit();
```

Comment: thanks it worked, is there a documentation on this specific topic that you could share?

Comment: here you can read all about fragments.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: hi @Kristjan please vote up if this answer helped. thanks